# Chamar uma função qualquer fora do main() em C++

Tags: c++, funções, compiladores

Bom dia, pessoal, estou usando um compilador online de C++. O GDB compiler. Minha dúvida é por quê não consigo chamar uma função fora do main(). A função está em outro arquivo, que importo no cabeçalho do código. Dentro de main() a função funciona corretamente, mas se tento chamar fora, mesmo após main(), não funciona. Sempre tenho que chamar funções dentro de main()? Alguma forma de fazer esse código funcionar? ex_34 deveria exibir um cout "Isso é um teste!!".

P.S.: São exercícios de codificação que estou fazendo, cada arquivo é um exercício diferente. Usando arquivos fica mais fácil de organizar e ainda pratico como importar um.

O Código:

```
/******************************************************************************

Welcome to GDB Online.
GDB online is an online compiler and debugger tool for C, C++, Python, PHP, Ruby, 
C#, VB, Perl, Swift, Prolog, Javascript, Pascal, HTML, CSS, JS
Code, Compile, Run and Debug online from anywhere in world.

*******************************************************
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "ex_34"

int main()
{
    //printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}

void teste(){
    ex_34();
}
```

```
file ex_34:
void ex_34(){
    std::cout << "Isso é um teste!!" << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Pessoal, não encontrei forma de editar a pergunta. A parte final do código é essa: ex_34(); Ignorem por favor a função teste().

Comment: Pra editar é só clicar em.... [edit] :-)

Comment: Tua main não faz nada. Em algum lugar, direta ou indiretamente, tens que chamar o `ex_34()` para executar a função

Answer (score -1):

o programa é controlado de dentro da função main , e ali dentro dessa , não tem nenhum comando , e por isso ela não faz nada   ! , e poderia ser assim :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "ex_34"   // creio que nesse include tenha alguns comandos
                   // como a funcao "teste();"
int main()
{
    // printf("Hello World"); 
    teste();   // aqui chama a funcao teste
               // Que precisa existir no include "ex_34"
    return 0;
}
```